# Cows and Bulls repetition

Tags: java, random

I've been attempting to write a cows and bulls program over the last few hours. In cows and bulls. The program is supposed to generate 4 non-repeating integers between 0 and 9 for the user to guess, but my program outputs a group of integers with some repeating values about 1 in 10 times. Everyone I've gone to hasn't found any errors, if you know a fix please help me. My program so far is as follows:

```
    Random rng = new Random();
    int pos1 = rng.nextInt(10);
    int pos2 = rng.nextInt(10);
    int pos3 = rng.nextInt(10);
    int pos4 = rng.nextInt(10);
    int norepeat = 0;

    while(norepeat == 0){
        if(pos1 == pos3 || pos1 == pos2 || pos1 == pos4){
            pos4 = rng.nextInt(10);
        }
        if(pos2 == pos1 || pos2 == pos3 || pos2 == pos4){
            pos2 = rng.nextInt(10);
        }
        if(pos3 == pos1 || pos3 == pos2 || pos3 == pos4){ 
            pos3 = rng.nextInt(10);
        }
        if(pos4 == pos3 || pos4 == pos2 || pos4 == pos1){
            pos4 = rng.nextInt(10);
        }
        else {
            norepeat = 1;
        }
}


    System.out.print(pos1);
    System.out.print(" " + pos2);
    System.out.print(" " + pos3);
    System.out.print(" " + pos4);
```

Comment: Shuffle a size 10 array of numbers (0 - 9) and use the first four indices (0 - 3).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd do.  Once this code has run, you'll have a set of four different integers, in the range 0-9.

```
Random rng = new Random();
Set<Integer> numbersFound = new HashSet<>();
while(numbersFound.size() < 4) {
    numbersFound.add(rng.nextInt(10));
}
```

This works because implementations of the `Set` interface enforce uniqueness.  Adding a number to the set, when it's already in there, has no effect.

Comment: Thanks David, but I discovered that my group of if statements were operating simultaneously and it resulted in errors when separating repeated integers. I changed it so that the second if statement wouldn't operate until the first one returned false, I did the same with the third and fourth and the numbers stopped repeating.

Answer (score 1):

In case you were wondering how to implement what [my comment states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925189/cows-and-bulls-repetition#comment67134211_39925189), the following code shows how.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // declare and populate a size 10 array of 0 - 9
    int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    // shuffle the array 'a'
    shuffleArray(a);

    // output the first four indices of 'a'
    System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d%n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
}

// method used to shuffle a passed in array 'ar' using the Durstenfeld shuffle
public static void shuffleArray(int[] ar) {
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);

        // simple swap
        int tmp = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

You could make the above code more efficient by only swapping four times, since you only need four numbers. You would then need to grab the last four indices of the array, instead of the first four, since the array is shuffled from end to start.

Here's a link to the [Durstenfeld shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime your

```
 if(pos4 == pos3 || pos4 == pos2 || pos4 == pos1){
            pos4 = rng.nextInt(10);
        }
```

is found to be not the case the code within the else statement is carried out.
one way to fix this is to do as resueman does in his answer.

However another possible solution is to replace the else statement with the following

```
 if(pos4!=pos1 && pos4!=pos3 && pos4!=pos2 && pos3!=pos2 && pos3!= pos1 && pos2!=pos1){
                norepeat = 1;
            }
```

this will check the values everytime and only exit the loop when the numbers are different, while at the same time keeping most of your code in tact.

Comment: It will take some more CPU time.

Comment: no argument there, i was mainly posting as an option for the OP to see one way he could have done it using similar principles to his original code.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that all of my if statements operated simultaneously. Iv'e since rewritten them so that they operate sequentially. Heres the updates source:

```
    Random rng = new Random();
    int pos1 = 123;
    int pos2 = 458;
    int pos3 = 143;
    int pos4 = 234;

    int norepeat = 0;

    pos1 = rng.nextInt(10);
    pos2 = rng.nextInt(10);
    while(norepeat == 0){
        if(pos2 == pos1){
            pos2 = rng.nextInt(10);
        }else{

            pos3 = rng.nextInt(10);
            if(pos3 == pos1 || pos3 == pos2){
                pos3 = rng.nextInt(10);
            }else{
                pos4 = rng.nextInt(10);
                if(pos4 == pos1 || pos4 == pos2 || pos4 == pos3){
                    pos4 = rng.nextInt(10);
                }else{
                    norepeat = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing your GCSE as a mock for mine I discovered random.sample which you can use to create a four digit series with no duplicates.

```
str(random.sample(range(9), 4))
```

Unfortunately, you will have to use multiple ".replace" commands to rid yourself of various square brackets, commas and spaces.